# Does __libc_init_array copy initialization data for global variables whose LMA and VMA is different?

Tags: init, libc

I read through [understanding the __libc_init_array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265295/understanding-the-libc-init-array/), but I have a question about C global variable initialization: Does __libc_init_array also copy plain C global initialized variables, if their VMA and LMA is different? Say, I have such an global array:

int myarray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

And my link script is like this:

```
sections
{
   ...
   .data : {
       *(.data)
    } >RAM AT>FLASH
   ...
}
```

Will __libc_init_array copy the initialization data from FLASH to RAM for myarray on startup?

I tried it in a simple hello world program, but it looked like the data were not copied. But it could be my link script problem.